# Can't run Anaconda installer on Linux terminal

Tags: python

I downloaded Anaconda2 (for Python 2.7) from the [website](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)  and when I try to run the installer the running stops when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the license conditions. Does anyone have any idea why it doesn't work ?

Comment: It's for Python 2.7

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `python -V`

Comment: What command are talking about ? ^^ Can you give me your email please so that I can send you a picture of my terminal with the excution of Anaconda ? I can't post picture on this website

Comment: Open a terminal Ctrl-Alt-T and run `python -V` what's the output

Comment: the output is : python  2.7.6

Comment: I don't know what happened but when I logged out and re-logged in while I was doing something else, I tried running the installer and it worked ! It's really strange ! Thank you for your time and your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Run the installer `bash Anaconda2-2.4.0 -Linux-x86_64.sh`

   Make sure you are using the correct version. There is a 32-bit version and a 64-bit version.

   ```
   Welcome to Anaconda3 2.4.0 (by Continuum Analytics, Inc.)

   In order to continue the installation process, please review the license
   agreement.
   Please, press ENTER to continue
   >>>
   ```
2. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Read the license (or not) and press <kbd>Q</kbd>

   ```
   Do you approve the license terms? [yes|no]
   [no] >>>
   ```
4. Type `yes` to accept the license and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   ```
   Anaconda3 will now be installed into this location:
   /home/aboettger/anaconda3

     - Press ENTER to confirm the location
     - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
     - Or specify a different location below

   [/home/aboettger/anaconda3] >>>
   ```
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to start the installation

Comment: Actually when I type "Enter" the running stops. I don't even get the chance to be asked to read or not the licence.

Comment: What do you mean with "the running stops"? Is there a bash prompt or `>>>`?

Comment: When I type "Enter" I have this message : " stopped     bash Anaconda2-2.4.0 -Linux-x86_64.sh "